# Javascript wheel dynamic abilities

Tags: javascript, sass, compass

I came across this wheel script that I'd like to possibly implement. However, I need the $ of wheel panels to be dynamic. The SASS had a variable in it already, but if I modify it to say 20, and add more div elements, the wheel still only shows 10. It looks like the mixins that calculate the angle use the $num-sides variable. I do see extra elements when it first loads, but they disappear as soon as the wheel is touched. What am I missing?

http://codepen.io/Aldlevine/pen/yGLqd

```
$num-wheels: 1;
$num-sides: 20;
$wheel-height: 10rem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one more place where `10` existed and should change to `20` (see the comment in the code below):

```
$('.wheel').momentus({
  u: 1,
  mass: 1000,
  wheelRatio: -1000,
  mouseRatio: 6,
  onChange: function(coords, velocity){
    console.log('update');
    $('.wheel > div').each(function(i){
      var angle = -(coords.y/2) + (360/20)*i; // <-- CHANGE 10 to 20 HERE
      $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(500px) rotate3d(1,0,0,'+angle+'deg) translate3d(0,0,122px)');
    });
  }
});
```

If you run it with only that change, the panels in the wheel are far too large. In order for it to look good, you should also halve the `$wheel-height` to `5rem`.

- [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwwRXV)

Comment: Good catch. I was thinking it might be in the JS somewhere but couldn't find it. This does work for 20, but not as well for random numbers. I need to find a solution that'll handle anywhere from maybe 6 or 7 up to 20. It looks like the $wheel-height will need to be computed off the # of sides as well?

Comment: setting it to $wheel-height: 10rem/($num-sides/10); seems to do the trick